# Plotting a time - value graph via command-line tools like gnuplot

Tags: shell, command-line, plot, gnuplot

Let's say I have a file named `data`:

```
02.03.14    17.00   0.00    17.00   Desc
01.03.14    2.82    1.68    1.14    Desc
02.03.14    1.04    0.00    1.04    Desc
06.03.14    6.00    0.00    6.00    Desc
06.03.14    2.30    0.00    2.30    Desc
06.03.14    2.30    0.00    2.30    Desc
```

I want to use the `1st` column as x-axis and the `4th` column as y-axis and create a time-value plot.

- How can I make my output more readable? The x-axis is not readable and the bigger values are making smaller values not readable, too.
- How do other graph types look like, e.g. point/line/filled based? Is there a better representation than using `lines` for a time-value graph?

This is what I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set timefmt '%d.%m.%Y'
set xdata time
set terminal png
set output 'output.png'
plot    'data' u 1:4 w lines, \
        'data' u 1:3 w lines, \
        'data' u 1:3 w lines
```

It produces:

[image]

Comment: Your question about making plots "more readable/beautiful" are very subjective. This site works better if you ask a specific question that can be clearly answered. What do you want to change? Every one may make a different plot from the same data depending on the story you want to tell. There's no one "right" plot.

Comment: @MrFlick I want to see more of the graph. Right now the value with 250 is making the other values hard to see. Also the x-axis description is a mess and is not readable.

Comment: Use a log-scale on the y-axis to solve your first problem.

Comment: No R content visible.If you want this done in R then you should start by building an example dataset in R with code.

Comment: @BondedDust I think I'll remove the r tag to avoid confusion :). Edit: OH you already did, ok thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the datafile should have been made available, if possible. Second like in one of the comments, if you have very large value like `250` and very small value like `2.5`, there is no other way than to set the y-scale to log (`set log scale y`).

The messy x-axis can be tidied by using proper tic interval (`set xtics start,incr,end`).